# Ember error while processing route: You must use Ember.set()

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I  can't understand what is the reason of this error (EmberJS 2.0):

```
Error while processing route: articles.index Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to set the `content` property (of <DS.RecordArray:ember379>) to ``. EmberError@https://narayna.zsw.iron/app/js/libs/ember-template-compiler.js:4473:15
```

My route is looks like:

```
App.ArticlesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('article').set('content', '');
  }
});
```

and model like:

```
App.Article = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Article.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 1,
  title: "My article",
  body: "Some text"
}];
```

Сan anyone help me?

Comment: `.set('content', '');` why do you have this in your route? For what do you need that?

Comment: There are multiple issues in your code :

* `findAll` returns an Array-like object, and you're overriding its content to a String.
* What your code reads (but doesn't do) is "Find all the data, then no matter what, change it to a String".

If you were to remove the `.set(...)`, your codewould be ok. But what is it you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are setting the content, but the reason you are getting that error is because `findAll` returns a promise.

```
model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('article').then( (article) => {
       article.set('content', '');
       return article;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not use ember-cli and ember-template-compiller assert looks like error. When I comment out line 1215 of it, all looks better.